# Web.config Transforms w/ Publish to AWS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, amazon-web-services

I want to have a test/stage environment in AWS (1 EC2, 1 RDS db) as well a production environment (LB'd EC2s and 1 RDS db).  Perhaps I'm missing something obvious but how can I setup AWS Deployment to allow me to target either environment and modify my configuration (connection strings, etc) per environment?

I am familiar with VS2012 WebDeploy and config transforms but in that case I am specifying a Publish Profile which determines which transform to use.  When deploying with AWS toolkit I don't see any options for this.

Comment: Every find out the way? My application is being published with a debug configuration - all my bundles are being spat out as individual files!

Comment: @Sethi yes, see answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Build Configuration (ie "AWSDevServer") and then create a web.AWSDevServer.config file that transforms your settings.  Use that build configuration when you publish to AWS.

Comment: I don't see anywhere to specify which configuration to use, else I would have been happy to use my Release config. The Elastic Beanstalk publish is a separate process to the visual studio's publish. (I've just re-read your question and realised you're not using Elastic Beanstalk - damn!)

Comment: The publish occurs in multiple steps.  You build, then you publish.  Simply use your release build settings (and web.config transform) then publish.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you using Elastic Beanstalk with the AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio. As noted above the built in deployment uses the "Debug" environment by default with no way to change it.  To deploy for other configurations (Staging, Release...) you must use the command line deployment tool typically found here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\Deployment Tool\awsdeploy.exe
```

Docs are here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSToolkitVS/latest/UserGuide/tkv-deployment-tool.html

The key here is to add the "DeploymentPackage={relative path}/package.zip" to your config.txt for deployment.  I created a simple batch file for each of my configurations (deploy_prod.bat, deploy_dev.bat).  Hope this helps!